# How to add Average along with sum

Tags: sql, oracle

My query is :

```
select
TIERING_2, ASP_NAME , 
sum(case when  SUBCASE_MEASURED = '1' AND FE_TYPE = 'ASP' AND CLOSE_MONTH = '3' and region = 'EEMEA' AND SCHEDULED_RESCHEDULED = 'Scheduled' then 1 else 0 end) DA_SCHEDULED,
sum(case when  SUBCASE_MEASURED = '1' AND FE_TYPE = 'ASP' AND CLOSE_MONTH = '3' and region = 'EEMEA' AND SCHEDULED_RESCHEDULED = 'Reactive'  then 1 else 0 end) FE_DELAY,
sum(case when  SUBCASE_MEASURED = '1' AND FE_TYPE = 'ASP' AND CLOSE_MONTH = '3' and region = 'EEMEA' AND SCHEDULED_RESCHEDULED = 'Reactive'  then 1 else 0 end)Onsite_Time,
sum(case when  SUBCASE_MEASURED = '1' AND FE_TYPE = 'ASP' AND  region = 'EEMEA' AND SCHEDULED_RESCHEDULED = 'Reactive' and LATE_START_CONF_INDICATOR = '0'then 1 else 0 end) Late_hours,
sum(case when  SUBCASE_MEASURED = '1' AND FE_TYPE = 'ASP' AND CLOSE_MONTH = '3' AND ASP_ON_TIME = '1' then 1 else 0 end) ON_TIME
from table_Control_kpi GROUP BY ASP_NAME , TIERING_2
```

However along with sum i want average onsite time.
Can someone help me to club the below query with the above query

```
SELECT AVG(ONSITE_TIME) 
FROM table_Control_kpi
WHERE SCHEDULED_RESCHEDULED = 'Reactive' 
  AND ASP_NAME='3D Networks' 
  AND SUBCASE_MEASURED = '1' 
  AND FE_TYPE = 'ASP' 
  AND CLOSE_MONTH = '3'
```

Comment: Some sample data would really be helpful here.

Comment: `Fe_delay` have same function as `Onsite_Time` so have same value

Comment: `AVG( CASE .... )` doesnt work?

Comment: yes it does.. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe use a [`window function`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions004.htm#SQLRF06174)?

```
SELECT TIERING_2, ASP_NAME ,
       --all the sums up there
       ,AVG(CASE 
          WHEN SCHEDULED_RESCHEDULED = 'Reactive' 
          AND ASP_NAME='3D Networks' 
          AND SUBCASE_MEASURED = '1' 
          AND FE_TYPE = 'ASP' 
          AND CLOSE_MONTH = '3'
        THEN ONSITE_TIME END) OVER ()
FROM table_Control_kpi GROUP BY ASP_NAME , TIERING_2
```